# difference between 接到 and 收到

Tags: meaning, usage, difference

Can you give me as many as example sentences where I can

1. use 接到 but not 收到
2. use 收到 but not 接到
3. use both 接到 and 收到, and their meanings are same
4. use both 接到 and 收到, and their meanings are different?

I'm trying to understand the difference in meaning between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> use 接到 but not 收到

When 接 (receive) in 接到 means to receive a person

把妻子接到美國(O)

把妻子收到美國(X)

> use 收到 but not 接到

Use 收到 when you take ownership of the object after you received it

收到禮物(O)

接到禮物(X)

收到工資(O)

接到工資(X)

> use both 接到 and 收到, and their meanings are same

When both 接到 and 收到 means "receive"

接到一封信(O)

收到一封信(O)

接到消息(O)

收到消息(O)

> use both 接到 and 收到, and their meanings are different

When 接到 means "connect to" and 收到 means "put away to"

把電綫接到室內 = Connect the wires to inside the house

把電綫收到室內 = Put away the wires to the house inside

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, 接到 is used when someone takes the initiative, but 收到 is more passive. For example,

A: 你**收到**我的短信了吗？　Have you received my message?

B：收到了。Yes, I do.

A：你明天能来机场**接**我吗？Can you come to the airport to pick-up me tomorrow?

B: 我正好明天有事情，不能去。I am sorry but I have something else to do tomorrow.

(In Chinese, the two words could be used interchangeably in some cases.)

天文台**接收到**一个神秘的宇宙信号。The observatory received a mysterious cosmic signal.

For your 4 cases, I try to provide some extreme examples.

[1] use 接到 but not 收到 (她没有接到球。- did not catch the basketball)

[2] use 收到 but not 接到 (我没有收到快递。- did not receive the mail order)

[3] use both 接到 and 收到. Their meanings are the same. 天文台**接收到**(接到)(收到)一个神秘的宇宙信号。

[4] use both 接到 and 收到. The meanings of them are different?

[4a] 我接过他递给我的玫瑰花。(I took the roses he handed over)

[4b] 我收到他寄给我的玫瑰花。(I received the roses he mailed to me)

We can use 接受 (accept) in the following sentences.

[5a] 我拒绝**接受**他递给我的玫瑰花。(I refuse to accept the roses he handed over)

[5b] 我拒绝**接受**他寄给我的玫瑰花。(I refuse to accept the roses he mailed to me)

There is another related verb 取. The target is not moving but you have to pick it up. Use the verb 收 when the target is moving towards you but you need not move. 接(球) means you have to actively move your hands to catch the moving target.